# Interpolation of count data with R

Tags: r, interpolation, bar-chart

I have a dataset of this kind:

```
January : 0
February : 0
March : 1
April : 2
May : 1
June : 3
July : 3
August : 2
September : 0
October : 1
November : 1
December : 0
```

I did a barplot with R and now I want to create a graphic (lines) interpolating these bars. How can I proceed?
And then if I would scale this new graphic to a secondary (right) axis?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to our site!  If you are looking for answers that explain how to do the interpolation in general terms, then this is the place to post your question. If you just want instructions on drawing those lines in `R`, then we need to migrate your question to a more appropriate community.  Please let us know your preference either by editing your question or flagging it for migration.

Comment: I simply need a good way to show graphically these data. Better migrate it then, I presume. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to interpolate data. Here is one solution using `approx`.

```
library(zoo)
my.months <-seq(as.Date("2013/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 12)
my.zoo <-zoo(c(0,0,1,2,1,3,3,2,0,1,1,0),my.months)

plot(my.zoo,type="h",lwd=6,col="red")
par(new=T)
plot(approx(my.zoo),type="l",yaxt = "n",ylab="",xlab="") #add new graph layer
axis(4,pretty(approx(my.zoo)$y)) #add y axis on the right side
```

[image]

**EDITS**

Additional questions from OP to "smooth" the line. If smoothing means smoother curves in the line, I would use `spline` instead of `approx`. You can play with the number of points in the spline by changing the `5` in the `spline` call.

```
plot(spline(my.zoo, n = 5*length(my.zoo)),type="l",yaxt = "n",ylab="",xlab="")
```

[image]

If smoothing means less ups and downs, I would use a polynomial regression instead of `approx`. Once again, you can adjust the fit by changing the order of the regression (6 in this case).

```
plot(my.zoo,type="h",lwd=6,col="red")
par(new=T)
reg <-lm(coredata(my.zoo)~poly(index(my.zoo),6))
plot(predict(reg),type="l",yaxt = "n",ylab="",xlab="")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible whit approx have a smoother approx curve?
For example between april and june produce a less sudden fall?

Comment: you can tweak the smoothing using the kernel bandwidth: `plot(density(my.zoo,width=2)); rug(my.zoo)`

Comment: I think "density" is not correct because it count how many zero, one, two, etc... I have and then give a probability density for this category...But applied to temporal distribution (my month) make no sense...I need a sort of bandwidth applicable for approx.

Comment: Updated my answer with two new solutions.

Comment: I meant less "up and down". The polynomial regression is quite good, but still a bit unfitting. For example why a peak in november? I would expected a more direct fall between august and december. I tryed also with other data, but the pol. regression created some artefacts...

Comment: I give up. I gave you three good methods for interpolation. What you want is not clear.